# How to handle edge case when iterating over cartesian product of sets in Python?

Tags: python, set

I have a function on zero or more [Pyomo sets](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/pyomo/browser/pyomo/trunk/pyomo/core/base/sets.py):

```
def myfunc(*sets):
    if len(sets) == 0:
         return # Do something else that is irrelevant here
    indices = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, sets)  # Cartesian product of sets
    for i in indices:
        call_some_other_function(*i)
```

This fails when I pass it a single set of integers, like

```
import pyomo.environ
myset = pyomo.environ.Set(initialize=[1, 2])
myfunc(*myset)
```

because then I'm evaluating `*i` on an integer. What's an elegant way of handling this situation?

Comment: `myset` isn't a list of sets, it's just a set. You have to pass in an iterable of sets, so something like `myset = [set([1, 2])]` or just `myset = [{1, 2}]`.

Comment: Please note that *"If you can think of a better one and have permissions to change it, go ahead"* applies **all the time**. Also @Blender is right, this isn't so much an edge case as invalid input, you should be calling `myfunc(myset)` if `myset` doesn't itself contain sets.

Comment: How is `set_a * set_b` legal?  I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'set'`.  Are you using some other class with a `__mul__` method instead of the built-in `set`?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Yes, it appears that I am. Apologies for that. I'll revise the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check if it is an `collections.Iterable` to catch cases where it is not iterable (lists, sets, etc. are iterables - integer aren't):

```
from collections import Iterable
a = 1
isinstance(a, Iterable) # returns False
a = [1,2,3]
isinstance(a, Iterable) # returns True
```

so just do a check before you pass it into the function:

```
if isinstance(myset, Iterable):
    myfunc(*myset)
else:
    # something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things harder by implementing your own Cartesian product.  Python's provided [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) since 2.6, and it works with any number of input sets.

```
import itertools


def args(*args):
    return repr(args)


def for_each_index(*sets):
    if not sets:
         print('No sets given.  Doing something else.')
         return
    for index in itertools.product(*sets):
        print('Do something with ' + args(*index) + '...')
    return
```

I added the `args` function solely to show the exact result of expanding `*args`.  You don't need it, except maybe for debugging.

Note also that there is no need to call `len` to test if a tuple is non-empty.  `if not sets:` will do.